# Tomcat not working

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

Initially, i ran `tomcatStart.bat` file and it allowed me open my J2EE project in browser but it didn't allow me to login. it returned a 500 error with memory error.

Now, the tomcat it self has crashed and it is giving the following message on command prompt.

in this file, the most important thing is in the middle. i.e

```
*RequestFilter: filter-init problem:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
1)*
```

please let me know if anyone has the solution for it

Answer (score 0):

Open your catalina.bat file in notepad which is in `tomcat dir -> bin` folder and add below parameters and restart the server.

```
set CATALINA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms512m -Xmx1024m 
-XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC”
```

There is already CATALINA_OPTS is defined. Make sure you set above parameter at that place only.

Answer (score 0):

Generally `OutOfMemoryError` happens when no more memory available in heap. You can change the max value allocated by JVM for heap by using `-Xmx` option. If you are using tomcat you should set `JAVA_OPTS` as following:

`export JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xmx1024m"` - for Unix

`set JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xmx1024m` - for Windows

First try this. Then start tomcat again. If id does not help examine your application. What causes the extra memory consumption? Is is a heavy application logic? Is it probably a bug? This depends on your application.

You are welcome to ask more concrete questions if they appear during your discovery. Good luck.

Comment: it didn't worked out and the statement that you shared was as it is in the file, not sure what the problem is . thank you for the reply anyways